# How do I include scripts in my AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, frontend

I am having an issue and it might be because I do not understand AngularJS fully. What I am trying to do is add some JS scripts into my HTML.

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/gantt.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="plandat"></div>
</body>
```

The problem is that I am using AngularJS and I am not sure how to integrate both JS together. Here is what my controller looks like.

```
angular.module('analyticsCtrl', ['rzModule', 'daterangepicker'])
  .controller('planDatController', function($templateCache, $scope, $http, $interval, $filter, uiGridGroupingConstants ){

Highcharts.ganttChart('plandat', {
title: {
    text: 'Plan Dat'
},

series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    data: [{
        id: 's',
        name: 'Start prototype',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 18),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20)
    }, {
        id: 'b',
        name: 'Develop',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
        dependency: 's'
    }, {
        id: 'a',
        name: 'Run acceptance tests',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 23),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 26)
    }, {
        name: 'Test prototype',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 27),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 29),
        dependency: ['a', 'b']
        }]
    }]
});


  })
```

In conclusion, it seems that the AngularJS runs first and does not have the highcharts script read before setting up the highcharts gantt chart that I am trying to have appear. Thank you ahead of time. My frontend/javascript work is very limited and I would love to learn something new.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Your code works in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/pe9771ViQceV3zV8BsrS?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

In your example I didn't saw that you:

1. Included the angularjs script.
2. Wrote the ng-app directive.

Here is a full working example from [here](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js/).

It uses different type of charts but the principles are the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Highcharts directive demo </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">

     <hc-chart options="chartOptions">Placeholder for generic chart</hc-chart>
     <hc-pie-chart title="Browser usage" data="pieData">Placeholder for pie chart</hc-pie-chart>

    <script>
        angular.module('myModule', [])
            // Directive for generic chart, pass in chart options
            .directive('hcChart', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    template: '<div></div>',
                    scope: {
                        options: '='
                    },
                    link: function (scope, element) {
                        Highcharts.chart(element[0], scope.options);
                    }
                };
            })
            // Directive for pie charts, pass in title and data only    
            .directive('hcPieChart', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    template: '<div></div>',
                    scope: {
                        title: '@',
                        data: '='
                    },
                    link: function (scope, element) {
                        Highcharts.chart(element[0], {
                            chart: {
                                type: 'pie'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: scope.title
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    allowPointSelect: true,
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                data: scope.data
                            }]
                        });
                    }
                };
            })
            .controller('myController', function ($scope) {

                // Sample options for first chart
                $scope.chartOptions = {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    },

                    series: [{
                        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                    }]
                };

                // Sample data for pie chart
                $scope.pieData = [{
                        name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
                        y: 56.33
                    }, {
                        name: "Chrome",
                        y: 24.03,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    }, {
                        name: "Firefox",
                        y: 10.38
                    }, {
                        name: "Safari",
                        y: 4.77
                    }, {
                        name: "Opera",
                        y: 0.91
                    }, {
                        name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
                        y: 0.2
                }]
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If You just copy and paste the code above into an html file you'll get the following output: [image: output].

But notice that it is better to split each directive to its own code (and the directive's markup).

Comment: Hi, so I did it the second way and the first way. Both times I am getting `Highcharts is not defined`. Any idea why?

Comment: I edited the answer and attached the result of my code. can you just copy and paste it into an html file and see if you get the charts in the image?